# SQL: Get the value from the 2nd last business day of the previous month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with historical cash_balances per date, currency and country.

I need to fill a column called "cash_balance_last_month" with the values from the column "cash_balance" on the second last business date of the previous month - which is defined as the second last date in the previous month for which there is data in the table.

So the table looks like this:

```
report_date / currency / country / cash_balance / cash_balance_last_month
2016-03-05  /   USD    /   US    /      110     /        NULL
2016-03-05  /   EUR    /   DE    /      130     /        NULL
2016-03-05  /   EUR    /   FR    /      240     /        NULL
2016-02-05  /   USD    /   US    /      105     /        NULL
2016-02-05  /   EUR    /   DE    /      125     /        NULL
2016-02-05  /   EUR    /   FR    /      245     /        NULL
2016-29-04  /   USD    /   US    /      100     /        NULL
2016-29-04  /   EUR    /   DE    /      120     /        NULL
2016-29-04  /   EUR    /   FR    /      250     /        NULL
2016-28-04  /   USD    /   US    /       95     /        NULL
2016-28-04  /   EUR    /   DE    /      115     /        NULL
2016-28-04  /   EUR    /   FR    /      255     /        NULL
...
2016-30-03  /   USD    /   US    /       90     /        NULL
2016-30-03  /   EUR    /   DE    /      117     /        NULL
2016-30-03  /   EUR    /   FR    /      257     /        NULL
```

Note that 2016-30-03 is the second last business day of March.

The table should look like this:

```
report_date / currency / country / cash_balance / cash_balance_last_month
2016-03-05  /   USD    /   US    /      110     /        95
2016-03-05  /   EUR    /   DE    /      130     /        115
2016-03-05  /   EUR    /   FR    /      240     /        255
2016-02-05  /   USD    /   US    /      105     /        95
2016-02-05  /   EUR    /   DE    /      125     /        115
2016-02-05  /   EUR    /   FR    /      245     /        255
2016-29-04  /   USD    /   US    /      100     /        90
2016-29-04  /   EUR    /   DE    /      120     /        117
2016-29-04  /   EUR    /   FR    /      250     /        257
2016-28-04  /   USD    /   US    /       95     /        90
2016-28-04  /   EUR    /   DE    /      115     /        117
2016-28-04  /   EUR    /   FR    /      255     /        257
...
2016-30-03  /   USD    /   US    /       90     /        NULL
2016-30-03  /   EUR    /   DE    /      117     /        NULL
2016-30-03  /   EUR    /   FR    /      257     /        NULL
```

The first entries, in this example 2016-30-03, will obviously not have a previous month to refer to.

How do I calculate this column "cash_balance_last_month"? I haven't been able to figure it out myself or find any related questions that could help me come up with a solution.

Help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: do you have a calendar table ? If you don't, you should

Comment: No I don't. Any good solutions without one?

Comment: Seems it doesn't depend on calendar date, but rather on presence of data in the table. You can simply calculate row_number on the data in the table, partition it by year/month (and country?) order by date desc, and get the value from the row where row_number=2 for the given month-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @table table
(report_date datetime , currency varchar(3),  country varchar(2), cash_balance int, cash_balance_last_month int)
insert into @table
values
(cast('2016-05-03'  as datetime),   'USD'    ,   'US'    ,      110     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-05-03'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'DE'    ,      130     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-05-03'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'FR'    ,      240     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-05-02'  as datetime),   'USD'    ,   'US'    ,      105     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-05-02'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'DE'    ,      125     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-05-02'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'FR'    ,      245     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-04-29'  as datetime),   'USD'    ,   'US'    ,      100     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-04-29'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'DE'    ,      120     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-04-29'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'FR'    ,      250     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-04-28'  as datetime),   'USD'    ,   'US'    ,       95     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-04-28'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'DE'    ,      115     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-04-28'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'FR'    ,      255     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-03-31'  as datetime),   'USD'    ,   'US'    ,       10     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-03-31'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'DE'    ,       10     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-03-31'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'FR'    ,       10     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-03-30'  as datetime),   'USD'    ,   'US'    ,       90     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-03-30'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'DE'    ,      117     ,        NULL),
(cast('2016-03-30'  as datetime),   'EUR'    ,   'FR'    ,      257     ,        NULL)

select  t1.report_date,t1.currency,t1.country,t1.cash_balance, s.cash_balance as cash_balance_last_month
from    @table t1
left join
(
select  t1.*,
        year(t1.report_date) * 12 +  month(t1.report_date) monthnum,
        row_number() over(partition by  year(t1.report_date) * 100 + month(t1.report_date), t1.country order by t1.report_date desc) rn
from    @table t1
) s
on  s.monthnum = (year(t1.report_date) * 12 +  month(t1.report_date))  - 1
    and t1.country = s.country and t1.currency = s.currency 
    and s.rn = 2
```

Comment: Dates localised to UK. Trick is to calculate a month number as well as a row number.